# how to change CopyRetryCount and CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds values in Visual Stdio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

VS 2017 often fails refreshing ASP.NET Core web applications with the following error message:

```
 Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms.
 ...
 Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms.
```

but when the second try, it runs ok. 
Question how to change/customize the configuration values of **CopyRetryCount** and **CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds** in a project?
I found a global settings in the file,

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

but what is the appropriate way to define a project level settings about those two?

Comment: Can you edit the two properties in your project file now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override those two properties, you can in your project *.csproj file. It will look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyRetryCount>2</CopyRetryCount>
  <CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds>Put some number here</CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You just hand edit your csproj file and put those values in there yourself.

Comment: Yes, it woks, thanks a lot. It is an occasional issue, it happened today, and only had 2 automatic tries, saved a lot time.